# How to turn off Named Pipe security?

Tags: security, winapi, named-pipes, dacl

I'm trying to create a named pipe between two Windows processes. The server process runs under a normal account, in a UI session. The client process runs in an unknown security context, apparently rather restricted.

Initially I called

```
pipe = CreateNamedPipeA(MY_PIPE_NAME, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, maxClients,
                     pipeChunkSize, pipeChunkSize, 0, nullptr);
```

I.e. leave pass no `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`. Usually, this works - no security means no security. Apparently, this is no longer the case for named pips. The caller tried

```
CreateFileA(MY_PIPE_NAME, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

and got back a `GetLastError=5`, access denied. Testing showed that this was due to a security failure; the exact same line would succeed if the client executable was run from a test environment in the same UI session as the server.

The logical solution would be to set the DACL to `SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY, KEY_ALL_ACCESS` (S-1-1-0) in the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` used for `CreateNamedPipeA`. This didn't fix the problem.

The only security downgrade left from "everybody can do everything"  would be "no security whatsoever". What do I have to do in `CreateNamedPipe` so that `CreateFileA` *never* fails with an Access Denied?

<sub>Security is pretty irrelevant here. `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` and `pipeChunkSize` already mean that the server is safe against buffer overflows by rogue clients.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want a pipe accessible by anyone (e.g. it's hosted in a service and I can't predict what account will need it), I add a NULL-DACL SD:

```
static SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES g_sa = {0};

g_sa.nLength = sizeof(g_sa);
g_hsa = GlobalAlloc (GHND,SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
g_sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = GlobalLock(g_hsa);
g_sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

if (InitializeSecurityDescriptor (g_sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, 1))
{
   if (SetSecurityDescriptorDacl (g_sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE,NULL,FALSE))
   {
      DebugMessage ("security descriptor DACL set OK\n");
```

where &g_sa is added as the param for CreateNamedPipe. Granted, this is blowing-the-bloody-doors-off territory, but if you want *anyone* to be able to access it, you don't have a lot of choice.